# how to free: MYSQL_ROW row;?

Tags: mysql, c

there is:

```
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
```

via function i can do

```
return row[0];
```

which means there has been memory allocated for it. and it needs to be freed.

there is a function to free the **MYSQL_RES *res;**

```
mysql_free_result(res);
```

but there does not seem to be any function to free the: **MYSQL_ROW row;**

why is this ?

Comment: It is not a pointer

Comment: The memory is allocated on the stack and does not need to be freed.

Comment: before the **return row[0];** i have **mysql_free_result(res);**  and yet "**row[0]**" contains data. so freeing the result does not seem to be freeing the row.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to free it. When you get results for a query they are stored in the result data structure and fetching rows returns data from within it. When you free the result all the data for the rows is also freed.

Also as you can see the `MYSQL_ROW` is not used as a pointer so it cannot be freed anyway.